# Solr multi core installation error

Tags: tomcat, solr, centos, tomcat6

My client has website which uses solr search which I am not expert on. He now needs to change the server. The previous server has two solr cores(ie: core0 and core1). I installed tomcat6 then added solr. I "rsynch"ed the previous server's solr directory to the new server so that all the schemas and settings are set quickly. But when I try to access the solr admin, I get this error:

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
core0: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: severeErrors
core1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: severeErrors
Please check your logs for more information


There are no SolrCores running. 
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.
```

Here is my solr.xml file:

```
<solr persistent="true">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:8080}" hostContext="${hostContext:solr}" defaultCoreName="core0">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
    <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
    <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory" class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
      <str name="urlScheme">${urlScheme:}</str>
    </shardHandlerFactory>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

What can be the problem? Please help

Comment: did you see solr/collection1/conf/ folder? ...Add the solrConfig.xml to that path...

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti There is no collection1 folder. I have searched the folder but could not find

Comment: Which solr version is that ?